# Can I restore a project backup file created using deprecated Appery library?

Tags: appery.io

Appery.io recently announced that they will soon be removing their deprecated JQM libararies (5.0, 5.1 and 5.2) from the system.  I have some Appery project backup files that were created using the deprecated 5.2 library.

Will I be able to restore these projects using these backup files once the deprecated libraries are not on the system?  Or will I need to recreate backup files using the 5.3 library?

Also if I am unable to convert a project to the 5.3 Appery library, will I be able to open the project on the Appery system once the deprecated libraries are removed?

Answer (score 1):

Steve, Appery.io converts such backups automatically if you restore the project from the backup. No need to convert it manually. So the short answer is: Yes, you can.